# queried layer is not updating after drawing new feature in original shapefile

Tags: qgis, update, query-layer

I have a project in qgis 1.8 where I added the same shapefile 3 times.  On 2 of them I made a query.  The third one is for edditing purposes.

When I change the value of one of the features (in the third shapefile) it is immediately rendered in the corresponding queried shapefile.  But, when I draw a new feature, nothing changes at all. But when I close and reopen my project, the new feature is drawn in the corresponding queried layer.

Is there a way to update a queried layer with new drawn features, without restarting your project?

thanks

Comment: you are making changes in third file and is done in memory and is only shared between other two layers when you update the layer. This is because after you load a file in QGIS and you removed it(not recommened) from your disk you still can visualize it on QGIS because features are already read by QGIS initally. during editing the layer itself will obivously responds to your queries. The other two layer (non editable) in your case is just a copy of data in disk. when you close and reopen it actually you are saving data and loding again